# Multiplying two numbers using jquery ajax in mvc2

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$('#txtDistance').change(function() {
    /*
    $.getJSON('/MYKPortal/Conveyance/GetRateByConveyanceType', { role: $("#ddlTypes").val() }, function(rate) {
        $("#txtRate").val(rate.rate);
    });
    */

    var distance = $(parseInt("#txtDistance").val());
    var rate = $(parseFloat("#txtRate").val());
    //var amount = $("#txtAmount").val(distance * rate);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(amount),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            $("#txtAmount").val(distance * Rate);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***jQuery*** does *unfortunately* not support a multiplication function. This means we have to resort to normal JavaScript (I apologise.. I'm sure John Resig is working on something...)

In the mean time, I *think* this does what you want, but as you didn't ask a question, I'm guessing:

```
var distance = parseInt($("#txtDistance").val(), 10);
var rate = parseFloat($("#txtRate").val());
var amount = distance * rate;

$("#txtAmount").val(amount);
```

Remember to specify a [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_Interpretations_with_No_Radix) for the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function

Comment: jQuery really is a joke not supporting basic operations like multiplication. I'm surprised anyone uses it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var distance = parseInt($("#txtDistance").val());
var rate = parseFloat($("#txtRate").val());
```

... and remember Javascript is case sensitive:

```
$("#txtAmount").val(distance * rate); // lower-case 'r'
```

Comment: yes i tried but no use thanks for the answer

Comment: @viswadattu - you are not being very helpful

Comment: thanks for the answer i got later